# Any Gnosis-Safe SDKs for Android/IOS?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I create a multi cryptocurrency wallet (native for Android and IOS) and want to integrate Safe in it. Do you have any SDKs for Android and IOS or any RESTfull APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the REST API, we have the Safe Transaction Service, and depending on the network you want to use, there are different endpoints for it: https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-api/available-services

It does not allow to execute transactions, but allows to send the transaction objects to the service, so it is available for all the signers of a Safe. They can retrieve it, sign it locally and submit the signature to the service. Once a transaction in the service has all the signatures, anyone can retrieve it an execute it with a local library.

The API also allows to return info about the configuration of a Safe account, the history of incoming and outgoing transactions, balances, etc.